# Passing this to a constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor, this, aggregation

In most of my java applications, I have a Controller (Logic) class and a GUI class. I usually need the Logic class to call methods on the GUI class, and vice versa. Now, when the Logic constructs the GUI, I pass a reference to "this" in the constructor so the GUI can call methods on the Logic. Here is some example code.

```
public class Logic {
   private int num = 2;
   private final GUI gui;

   public Logic(){
       gui = new GUI(this);
   }

   public int getNum(){
      return num;
   }
}


public class GUI {
   private final Logic logic;

   public GUI(Logic logic){
      this.logic = logic;
   }

   public void calledLater(){
      int num = logic.getNum();
   }
}
```

My question is: Is this the best OO way to create an aggregation relationship, or am I messing up my design?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using 'this' as a parameter to a method call in a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127205/using-this-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-call-in-a-constructor)

Comment: @CoolBeans it does not look like a duplicate, only the title is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `this` to a UI class is not in itself a problem, as long as the methods of the class are not called through `this`, as in your example. You call `getNum` right in the constructor of the `GUI`, which should be avoided: your `Logic` class may not be ready to return the correct result.

One thing to note is that you couple your `GUI` to the `Logic` class, which may be too much coupling. You should consider extracting an interface from `Logic`, and let `GUI` interact only with what's intended for it:

```
interface DataSourceForTheGui {
    int getNum();
}

class Logic implements DataSourceForTheGui {
    int getNum() {
        return n;
    }
}

class GUI {
    private readonly DataSourceForTheGui data;
    public GUI(DataSourceForTheGui data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void display() {
        int k = data.getNum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The getNum() thing was just a bad example. I will remove. But the interface idea is very good, and I will use it from now on. I am not sure I want to take on a full MVC design for small applications like the one I am working on now.

Answer (score 4):

In the design you've posted, there's a tight coupling between your UI and your model. This is somewhat frowned upon if building large/formal/serious/long-lived systems. There's a well known pattern of architecting UI/Model architecture known as [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that addresses this.

Whether or not you need to worry about going to town on making an MVC styled architecture really depends on the context of your app and your desires for it in the future. But you should read up on MVC and know that it is there.

Btw, I see in your code a ["code smell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): two objects, A and B, each holding a reference to each other. There is usually a more desirable way of doing things than having cyclic references. You can avoid this by having, for example, object A holding a reference to B (and perhaps even 'owning' it), and B pushing data of interest to A via notifications, or the observer pattern, etc. This avoids B having to have any specific info about A, or even having to know that it exists. Voila, less coupling in your design, so you end up with more scope for code re-use, and a less brittle system that is easier to change.

An important and central design pattern in Cocoa (and Cocoa Touch) is the delegate pattern. This pattern involves using protocols (similar to interfaces in other langs like Java) to decouple the producer and consumer of information, events, etc.

I suggest reading [this excellent reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/02_DesignPatterns.html) from Apple about fundamental design patterns in Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I'm ok with GUI holding an instance of Logic. After all, if the GUI is supposed to use the Logic object, it's going to have to access it somehow.

However, I would rather see Logic NOT construct GUI. If you really want model and view to be separate, I think that you would construct Logic somewhere, and construct GUI with the Logic object. Then, if Logic ever needs to update the GUI for whatever reason, you should have it generate an event.

In that case, Logic needs to have a list of event listeners, so that whenever it generates an event, all the event listeners are notified. The GUI then registers with Logic as a listener, and is thus able to receive all the events.

Some good classes for this are java.util.EventListener and java.util.EventObject.

But really, that's only necessary if Logic needs to communicate up to GUI asynchronously. Otherwise, just stick with Logic not constructing the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it will work, but I'd never ever reference a GUI object from your business logic.

- I'll answer with comments.  What are you trying to do?
- your user should instruct your GUI, and the GUI should properly instruct the Logic to do what it needs to do, and return results back to the GUI.

Few other comments:

- I'd make your Logic num member a constant since it's not changing
- If you're not changing your Logic object ever for your GUI, there's no reason to pass it into your constructor.
- If you want to change your Logic object, I'd make a property called Logic in your GUI class so you can get access to it and change it when necessary.
- If you really want to get fancy, you'd keep your Data Access Layer (business logic) in a separate library from your GUI so all of your interfaces/applications can utilize it.  Then you'd import your Logic library into any interfaces that need it.

Comment: The num is just an example. It would be constant if I didn't plan to change it. And on bullet #2, how could I have access to a reference to logic without passing it in the constructor?

Comment: GUI g = new GUI();  // no parameters in constructor
g.Logic.doSomething(); //if Logic is a public property ... but again, I would have controls in your interface that pass arguments to the GUI object after it has a reference to it, and then the GUI can be it's own black box to talk to the logic.  The user shouldn't have to worry about logic.  Only the GUI cares about the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing (or at least the easiest to understand) is to have the initial thing created as an outside class (called directly by the main class or the main class itself). So your code would look somewhat like this.

```
public class MainClass{

public static void main(String[] args){
l = new Logic();
g = new GUI(l);
l.setGUI(g);
}

public static Logic l;
public static GUI g;

}
```

Comment: I like the idea. I think I will do it, although I would use a setter for both, instead of passing l in the constructor.

Comment: It's not a very good idea for the 'logic' part to know about the gui. The GUI should be a separate concern outwith the logic -- these two things should ideally not be so tightly coupled. This is where the 'controller' in MVC comes in handy.

Comment: Did I misuse the term "Logic"? I am trying to use it synonymously with Controller. In most of my applications, a Logic contains a GUI and Workers. The Workers do heavy computation, and the Logic/Controller facilitates communication.